# How to get list of connected users in PeerJS server (with express)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to use PeerJS (a webRTC library) for a game and triyng to use the server they provide for doing user discovery. I want to manage a list of connected users and I'm struggling with PeerJS server.

In the doc they say we can have a PeerJs and an Express server in the same app.

Here is the code :

```
// this doesn't work
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { res.send('Hello world!'); });

var server = app.listen(9000);

var options = {
    debug: true,
    allow_discovery: true
}

app.use('/api', ExpressPeerServer(server, options));

server.on('connection', function(id) {
    // we get a socket object as id :( 
    // should be a string
    console.log(id)
});

server.on('disconnect', function(id) { console.log(id + "deconnected") });
```

Nevertheless, when a user connects, I get a `socket` object as `id`, which is not what I want. Also I can't access to the connected peers at the url `http://localhost:9000/peerjs/peers`

---

What is strange is that, using only PeerJS server, it works as expected (I get the string ID of the peer), and I can access to the connected peers at the url `http://localhost:9000/peerjs/peers`.

```
// this works 
var ip = require('ip');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;

var port = 9000;
var server = new PeerServer({port: port, allow_discovery: true});

server.on('connection', function (id) {
  // id is correct (a string)
  console.log('new connection with id ' + id);
});

server.on('disconnect', function (id) {
  console.log('disconnect with id ' + id);
});

console.log('peer server running on ' +
            ip.address() + ':' + port);
```

---

Any clues to make PeerJS server work with express ?
Is it a regression about the express compatibility ?

Thanks a lot :)

---

System infos :

- `node -v : v0.10.25`
- Ubuntu 14.04
- peerJS server installed from github with : `npm install peers/peerjs-server` (version: "0.2.8")

Answer (score 4):

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000);
var q = ExpressPeerServer(server, options);
app.use('/peer', q);
q.on('connection', function (id) {
    console.log('user with ', id, 'connected');
});
```

this should work

Answer (score 2):

Just incase anyone having same issue all you need to do is:

```
server.on('disconnect', function (client) 
{
    // this will give you id in text or whatever format you are using
    console.log('disconnect with id ' + client.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the undocumented `listAllPeers(function cb(list){})` function if you run your own peerjs-server.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference to your own answer here: https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server/issues/86

And in combination with SocketIO: http://stephantabor.com/2015/07/11/express-peerjs-and-socket-io/